# How to refresh the contents of the folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am recording the screen and saving it in a Particular folder and then after saving it i have a button to show all the videos in that folder.
newly saved videos are not updating but if i go in file-explorer and open that folder there the video is showing and then if i again see all videos of that folder in my app ,now the video appears there too .How to make that video appear first time only i.e after saving the video if i click (view all video) button the video should be there.

My code for fetching all videos from folder

```
private void init()
{
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),4);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList,Video_Main.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
    fetch_videos();
}

private void fetch_videos()
{
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data,thum;
    String absolutePathImage = null;

    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA
    };
    String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%Paint App%"};
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,orderBy +" DESC");
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    thum = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA);

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        absolutePathImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        VideoModel videoModel = new VideoModel();

        videoModel.setBoolean_selected(false);
        videoModel.setStr_path(absolutePathImage);
        videoModel.setStr_thumbnail(cursor.getString(thum));
        arrayList.add(videoModel);
    }
    videoAdapter.setVideoList(arrayList);
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.parse(root + "/Paint App")));
}
```

}

Comment: after add, remove or update of contents just notify updation in adapter class. `videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: not working . not solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method in the adapter like,

```
public void setVideoList(YourArray arrayList){
  this.yourList.clear();
  this.yourList.addAll(arrayList);
  notifyDataSeChanged();
}
```

then remove below lines and add it outside the method but above that method,

```
VideoAdapter videoAdapter = new 
VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList,Video_Main.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
```

Also, call the method from adapter from where you removed the lines,

```
videoAdapter.setVideoList(arrayList);
```

then when you add record the file just call the method again fetch_videos(); It will work.

Comment: i have updated the code as you suggested,not working.Now nothing is been shown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,i got the solution my sendBroadcast was wrong.It should be

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(file)));
```